# Bolding text in console output

Tags: c, unix, text-formatting

For extra credit, the professor wants us to use bolding and/or underlining to text output in the current project.

The example he gave was `b\bb o\bo l\bl d\bd` is displayed as **b o l d**

Following that example, I marked up `SPACE` as
`printf("\033[7mS\bSP\bPA\bAC\bCE\E- move forward one page\033[0m");`

I'm also implementing reverse video by enclosing strings within `\033[7m` and `\033[0m` fields.  The reverse video inverts the colors of the line appropriately, but doesn't seem to be affecting the bolding, since both strings with and without the reverse video are not bolding.

Could it be the standard shell used in Ubuntu 10.10 that is at fault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree about using curses, but given your starting point ....

I think you want to use the 'bright' feature of VT100 for the bold, `ESC[1m`

You can probably find better doc on VT100 codes, but using this page I found the codes. [ANSI/VT100 Escape Codes](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm)

I hope this helps.

Comment: You were right.  It was a combination of both, and `\033[1m` needed to be inserted in the string containing the text to be bolded.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you're just trying to be masochistic, try using curses (or ncurses) instead.

```
// warning: Going from distant memory here...
curs_attron(A_INVERSE); // maybe A_REVERSE? I don't remember for sure.
curs_addstr("SPACE - move forward one page");
curs_attroff(A_INVERSE);
```

Comment: It was the example that was given.. and I have to admit that the strings are looking pretty wonky when VT100 control characters sprinkled throughout.  I'll remember this for the future.

Comment: Even if you're going to do it on your own, I'd still do a bit like curses, and write a few functions to handle the video attributes separately from the printing and such. As to the part about Ubuntu specifically, that's a harder to say, but as little as things like this get used anymore, a bug could go uncaught for a while. Conversely, as little as it gets modified, a bug being introduced seems unlikely...